# What are the anti-patterns and errors in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Could you help me to figure out the anti patterns and problems in my code. I can't seem to figure out the anti patterns of this code and the solution. I've fixed some errors but I believe there are still many mistakes:

```
class Stringchecker():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def check_pass(people_text):
        result = []
        for k in people_text:
            if people_text[k] =="pass":
                result.append(k)
            else:
                return result


if __name__== "__main__":
    people_text = {'Mia': 'pass', 'Mike': 'fail', 'Jack': 'pass')
    sc = StringChecker()
    print sc.check_pass(people_text)
```

Comment: There are a few syntax errors in this code. Is this an error with you re-typing the code here, or is this the exact code you are trying to run on your end?

Comment: check_pass is missing the first argument ``self``

Comment: I am trying to run this code without the anti pattern issues. I just don't know how to make it that way

Comment: If this is the entire code of StringChecker, I see no reason to even have a class instead of a free function.

Comment: You forgot the **self** in check-pass.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several syntax issues and some logic problem. Also you are not using [**`class constructor`**](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) properly, just giving it a `pass` is not a good practice. Another thing is to use [**`list comprehension`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for your `check_pass` method. I made some corrections to your code:

```
class StringChecker(object):

    def __init__(self, people_text):
        self.people_text = people_text

    def check_pass(self):
        return [k for k, v in self.people_text.items() if v == "pass"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = StringChecker({'Mia': 'pass', 'Mike': 'fail', 'Jack': 'pass'})
    print sc.check_pass()
```

Output:

```
['Mia', 'Jack']
```

**Note**: Updated list comprehension with suggestion from @**JLPeyret**

Comment: return [k for k,v in self.people_text.items() if v == "pass"]

Comment: @abc12333333:  Nice rewrite of the class.  For the anti-patterns see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36341657/208880).

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

- not using `self` as first parameter to `check_pass`
- returning the `result` after the first failure (if no failures, `result` will not be returned; if a failure occurs before successes would, `result` won't have all the data)
- `return result` should be at the same indentation level as `for k in ...`

Anti-patterns:

- a `class` with only one non-`__init__` method (just use a function)
- (assuming `else` branch has a `pass` instead) - useless `else` branch